# Reloading of data not happening for the second request

Tags: dojox.grid.datagrid

I have EnhancedGrid which loads data after getting response from AJAX call based on my query to database.
When i make the first request i can see the  data to be populated in grid correctly. However, i change my query it still loads the previous data. My response returns correct data from database in JSON.

I tried in all possible ways and debugged using firebug but unable to get the output. I tried searching the similar post but still it didn't work for me.Any help would be much appreciated. 
I am pasting my code below.

```
_initialiseGrid:function(){

var layout = [
              {'name': 'Project Name', 'field': 'projectName', 'width': '200px'},
              {'name': 'Date Created', 'field': 'createdDate', 'width':       '100px',formatter:this.formatDate},
              {'name': 'Comments', 'field': 'senderComments', 'width': '250px',editable:true}                    
             ];

 dataGrid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
            id: 'JoinProjectGrid',
            structure: layout,
            rowSelector: '20px',
            plugins: {indirectSelection: {headerSelector:true}}},
            document.createElement('div'));

}

_loadData:function(response){

     var projectList=response.retrievedList;
     var rowData = {
                    identifier: "projectId",
                    items: projectList
                   };
     dataStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data: rowData});
     dataGrid.set("store",dataStore);
     dojo.byId("gridDivForJoin").appendChild(dataGrid.domNode);
     dataGrid.startup();

   }
```

i tried using :

```
dataGrid.setStore(dataStore)
```

which is not working for the second request so, 
i used dataGrid.set("store",dataStore) which is not loading the new data but shows previous one.I also tried :

```
clearOnClose:true, urlPreventCache:true
```

to refresh the grid and used below code also to clear the store on second request.

```
 var newStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data: {  identifier: "",  items: []}});
  dataGrid.setStore(newStore);
```

Answer (score 0):

i got it worked after adding

```
dataGrid.render()
```